# How to make script file to run several commands on several terminals in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to open three terminals and each terminal should go to three directories and need to run three files on those three terminals. Now I need  speed up my task. Beacuse of that need to do it by running a single script file.How can  I do that?

As a example I have to run those three commands on three terminals. But I need to do those thing using one single file running.

```
cd /home/xyz/Desktop/project/components/core;
python3 Main.py

aria2c --enable-rpc

cd /home/xyz/Desktop/project/ui;
gulp serve
```

Comment: Placing commands in a single script won't make things faster just like that.

Comment: What kind of terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: This posting can be useful for your question
https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the

Comment: Why do you need 3 terminals? is it because you are running your commands in 3 different local directories? or on 3 different servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends suggested this as an answer and it worked for me.I can run those terminal commands with & operator and then those commands run on background and they will run on the same terminal without any failure.I created a single file using below commands and when I run it, that file prompt to run those commands in same terminal.

## !/bin/bash

cd /home/xyz/Desktop/project/components/core;python3 main.py  &
aria2c --enable-rpc &
cd /home/kaveesh/Desktop/project/ui;gulp serve &

Comment: How does this address the issue of running from 3 separate locations? Doesn't this require you to write the same code 3 times in a row, changing the directory between commands?

Comment: Single ampersand "& " can also delimit a list of commands to be run asynchronously.This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously.                                          

" ./file1.py & ./file2.py & ./file3.py &  "

In this example, all 3 python scripts are run at the same time, in separate sub-shells. Their stdout will still be attached to the parent shell, so if running this from a Linux terminal, you will still see the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your commands in one bash file like those below and run it from terminal.

```
gnome-terminal -e command_1
gnome-terminal -e command_2
gnome-terminal -e command_3
```

Look here for more details https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the